# '[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)[3].(2)'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, togglebutton

How can I fix this exception caused by the folling style?

```
        <Style x:Key="OnOffSwitchToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-0.033">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.456*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.544*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="Switch">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.083"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path1">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="path">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="#FF39B54A"/>
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="#FF319D40"/>
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="label">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#00999999"/>
                                                <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="#0039B54A"/>
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="White"/>
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContentControl.Content)" Storyboard.TargetName="label">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="ON"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment)" Storyboard.TargetName="Switch">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="{x:Static HorizontalAlignment.Left}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="Switch">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="39.965"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="label">
                                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="-19.224"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="Switch">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="label">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="label">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#00999999"/>
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="#00999999"/>
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="#FF999999"/>
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Canvas x:Name="_switch" UseLayoutRounding="False" Height="30" Width="70" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalMargin" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                <Canvas x:Name="Background" Height="30" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="70" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform/>
                                            <SkewTransform/>
                                            <RotateTransform/>
                                            <TranslateTransform/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                    <Path x:Name="path" Height="30" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="70" Data="F1M55.0161,-0.966799999999999L14.9831,-0.966799999999999C6.7081,-0.966799999999999,0.00010000000000332,5.7412,0.00010000000000332,14.0162C0.00010000000000332,22.2922,6.7081,29.0002,14.9831,29.0002L55.0161,29.0002C63.2911,29.0002,70.0001,22.2922,70.0001,14.0162C70.0001,5.7412,63.2911,-0.966799999999999,55.0161,-0.966799999999999" Fill="#FFEDEDED" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FFCCCCCC">
                                        <Path.Effect>
                                            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="#FF00ADEF" Opacity="0"/>
                                        </Path.Effect>
                                    </Path>
                                </Canvas>
                                <Grid x:Name="Switch" Height="22" Canvas.Left="4.815" Canvas.Top="3.568" Width="22" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform/>
                                            <SkewTransform/>
                                            <RotateTransform/>
                                            <TranslateTransform/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <Grid.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="0.5"/>
                                    </Grid.Effect>
                                    <Path x:Name="path1" Data="F1M14.9614,27.0166C7.7934,27.0166,1.9614,21.1846,1.9614,14.0166C1.9614,6.8486,7.7934,1.0166,14.9614,1.0166C22.1294,1.0166,27.9614,6.8486,27.9614,14.0166C27.9614,21.1846,22.1294,27.0166,14.9614,27.0166" Height="22" Stretch="Fill" Width="22" Margin="0" Fill="White"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Canvas>
                            <Label x:Name="label" Content="OFF" Grid.Column="1" Margin="-2.506,2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Avenir 45" FontSize="14.667" Foreground="#FF999999" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <Label.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Label.RenderTransform>
                            </Label>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        </Style>
```

I'm applying this style to a toggle button which is inside a Grid cell:

```
<ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ObjectStatus}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=OnOffSwitchToggleButton}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
```

I have another toggle button inside a devexpress GridControl and this exception does not appear.

Comment: if i paste your code in kaxaml all works fine...

Answer (score 11):

As John said the error is in this line

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="Switch">
```

it is unable to iterate and lookup the property in switch so the solution is to give the transform a name and then reference the transform directly

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchTranslate">
```

and

```
<Grid x:Name="Switch" Height="22" Canvas.Left="4.815" Canvas.Top="3.568" Width="22" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="SwitchTranslate"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
```

Comment: This fixed it for me.  Using the name of the property instead of drilling down into the children, stopped it from crashing

Answer (score 1):

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="Switch">
```

This is the offending line where '(0).(1)3' where:

- (0) is (UIElement.RenderTransform),
- (1) is (TransforGroup.Children),
- [3] is [3], and
- (2) is (TranslateTransform.Y)

Doesn't help much, but I was running into similar problems. I think if you comment out
that line, the problem will go away, but might not work. Perhaps someone with more
experience with this kind of issue can chime in here.

Answer (score 0):

Below is  your fixed style:

```
<Style x:Key="OnOffSwitchToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-0.033">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.456*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.544*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="Switch">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.083"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path1">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="path">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="#FF39B54A"/>
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="#FF319D40"/>
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="label">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#00999999"/>
                                                <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="#0039B54A"/>
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="White"/>
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContentControl.Content)" Storyboard.TargetName="label">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="ON"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment)" Storyboard.TargetName="Switch">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="{x:Static HorizontalAlignment.Left}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="Switch">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="39.965"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="label">
                                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="-19.224"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="Switch">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="label">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="label">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#00999999"/>
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="#00999999"/>
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="#FF999999"/>
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Canvas RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="_switch" UseLayoutRounding="False" Height="30" Width="70"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
<Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform/>
                                            <SkewTransform/>
                                            <RotateTransform/>
                                            <TranslateTransform/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Canvas.RenderTransform>

                                <Canvas x:Name="Background" Height="30" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="70" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform/>
                                            <SkewTransform/>
                                            <RotateTransform/>
                                            <TranslateTransform/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                    <Path x:Name="path" Height="30" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="70" Data="F1M55.0161,-0.966799999999999L14.9831,-0.966799999999999C6.7081,-0.966799999999999,0.00010000000000332,5.7412,0.00010000000000332,14.0162C0.00010000000000332,22.2922,6.7081,29.0002,14.9831,29.0002L55.0161,29.0002C63.2911,29.0002,70.0001,22.2922,70.0001,14.0162C70.0001,5.7412,63.2911,-0.966799999999999,55.0161,-0.966799999999999" Fill="#FFEDEDED" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FFCCCCCC">
                                        <Path.Effect>
                                            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="#FF00ADEF" Opacity="0"/>
                                        </Path.Effect>
                                    </Path>
                                </Canvas>
                                <Grid x:Name="Switch" Height="22" Canvas.Left="4.815" Canvas.Top="3.568" Width="22" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform/>
                                            <SkewTransform/>
                                            <RotateTransform/>
                                            <TranslateTransform/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <Grid.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="0.5"/>
                                    </Grid.Effect>
                                    <Path x:Name="path1" Data="F1M14.9614,27.0166C7.7934,27.0166,1.9614,21.1846,1.9614,14.0166C1.9614,6.8486,7.7934,1.0166,14.9614,1.0166C22.1294,1.0166,27.9614,6.8486,27.9614,14.0166C27.9614,21.1846,22.1294,27.0166,14.9614,27.0166" Height="22" Stretch="Fill" Width="22" Margin="0" Fill="White"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Canvas>
                            <Label x:Name="label" Content="OFF" Grid.Column="1" Margin="-2.506,2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Avenir 45" FontSize="14.667" Foreground="#FF999999" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <Label.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Label.RenderTransform>
                            </Label>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        </Style>
```

Comment: This is hat I add to your XAML

Comment: This is what I add to your XAML:

Comment: Hi Lana, thanks for answering the question, can you perhaps give a short summary in the question of what you fixed in the style? Also, you can edit questions and comments instead of posting a new one.

Comment: There is any [edit] link below your answer. Please include a description of what you did to arrive at this code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more likely that the Children collection of the TransformGroup doesn't have 4 elements (yet), so `(TransforGroup.Children)[3]` gives an exception. Make sure that the transform doesn't run before the `Children` collection is set.